# Proper way to send GET parameters via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS, a GET request can be done by using:

> $http({method:'GET', url:'',
>   params:{:}}).success(function(data){       ...

Usually, in place of param value I use $form.name where name is a ng-model bounded to a text box.

My question is, that name may contain character like '&'. How to encode such characters when sending data via angular ?

Comment: Well, you would use `encodeURIComponent`, but are you sure Angular doesn't encode for you? Can you show a small example of exactly what you're trying to pass as params?

Answer (score 0):

Like given in the above comment, encodeURIComponent will work. But if you want to support old browsers also, you can easily do an encoding by yourselves. You can get all the URL Encoding Reference from W3schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp